# No Solution on simple VBA code to Sort Data on a hidden worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

This is my code, here is the problem

1. N column must sort Largest to Smallest
2. P Column must sort Z to A
3. Row 3 is where the headers are at, Rows 4 to 1000 is where the data is at.
4. Without the code below, when I record a macro to do this, it's fine, but when I add it to a main macro that runs different macros, which is on another sheet, it does not work.

```
Sub SortLost()    
    Worksheets("Lost Data").Sort.SortFields.Clear     
    Range("F3:P1000").Sort Key1:=Range("N3"), Key2:=Range("P3"), Header:=xlYes, _    
                           Order1:=xlAscending, Order2:=xlDescending    
End Sub
```

Comment: You haven't qualified the `Worksheet` for your `Range` calls.

Comment: What does the qualified mean?

Comment: `Worksheets("Lost Data").Range("F3:P1000")` and so on. Or you can use a `With` statement to save some typing: `With Worksheets("Lost Data")`, `.Range("F3:P1000").Sort Key1:=.Range("N3")...`, `End With`. Note the period `.` before each `Range` call.

Comment: Showing as an error

Comment: Sub SortLost()

Worksheets("Lost Data").Sort.SortFields.Clear
Worksheets("Lost Data").Range("F3:P1000").Sort Key1:=Range("N3"), Key2:=Range("P3"), Header:=xlYes, _
Order1:=xlAscending, Order2:=xlDescending

End Sub

Comment: You need to qualify every `Range`... that includes `Range("N3")` and `Range("P3")`.

Comment: Got it, I got it to call. Now, it's not sorting....Does something look off in the code? The headers are in Row 3, the data is in 4 to 1000

Comment: It is the P column that is not sorting

Comment: I'm not sure. You could always use the macro recorder here and compare the generated code to the above snippet.